# rust custom indexable data types

Tags: rust, operators

Is it possible to create custom data types in rust that can be indexed like Vec and Slice? If yes which Traits do I need to implement?

Example for indexed access:

```
let mut vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
assert_eq!(vec[1], 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the traits are called [`Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) and [`IndexMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html).